# how to pass session id for multiple pages?

Tags: c#, session, gridview

I have two pages and I'm passing session id to two pages. It works fine but in form1 I want to open form2 and form3 simultaneously. What should be the condition so that I would be able to open both the forms?

```
string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text + ' ' + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
  Session.Add("First_Name", name);
 Response.Redirect("General_Bill.aspx?First_Name=" + this.lblname.Text);
 Response.Redirect("Add_admission_record.aspx?First_Name=" + this.lblindex.Text);
```

Above code is only opening form2.aspx and not form3. Please guide me accordingly.

Comment: Do you want open both page at same time? :O

Comment: The first Redirect terminates the execution of your method, so the second one will not run.

Comment: no when i click Add_admission_record in that form one image button is there and that imgae button i give above form link.i mean when previous page is Add_admission_record then open Add_admission_record otherwise open General_Bill.

Comment: i know that treaschf...but i want to use if else condition for opening pages.

Comment: So on what condition you want to do this ?

Comment: if previous page is General_Bill then open General_Bill otherwise open Add_admission_record

Comment: And you have stored prevoius page name in session or you will be redirected from that page ?

Comment: just send variable through the query, and make decision open which page

Comment: how to use query ..can you give me example for that ..peyman

Comment: Is name of prevoius page in session ?

Comment: i pass session on load page of prevoius page..

Answer (score 1):

use this code and pass id multiple pages.

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTION">
       <ItemTemplate>
     <%-- <asp:LinkButton ID="id" runat="server" OnClientClick="ram(<%#Eval("id")%>"></asp:LinkButton>--%>

     <a href ='<%#"ViewAddmissionform.aspx?id="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"id")  %>'> View </a>/
     <a href ='<%#"EditAddmissionform.aspx?id="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"id")  %>'>Edit </a>/
     <a href ='<%#"Student Report.aspx?id="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"id")  %>'>Attendance </a>/
      <a href ='<%#"PrintRegisrationForm.aspx?id="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"id")  %>'>Print </a>

       </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text + ' ' + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
Session.Add("First_Name", name);
string pageName = Session["First_Name"].ToString();
    if(pageName.ToUpper()=="GENERAL_BILL.ASPX")
      Response.Redirect("General_Bill.aspx?First_Name=" + this.lblname.Text);
    else
      Response.Redirect("Add_admission_record.aspx?First_Name=" + this.lblindex.Text);
```

Comment: It gives error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: what is name of your session ?

Comment: First_Name is my session name.

Comment: its only open Add_admission_record form it doesn't open General_Bill form

Comment: check the spelling of geenral_bill in session variable and write same in if condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74162/discussion-between-pradnya-bolli-and-mairaj-ahmad).

Answer (score 0):

Create a session variable on in your code behind (I assume you are working with webforms).

Example

```
Session["Name"] = name;
```

And than to get access of this Session variable on next page you can get it by using below code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"].ToString();
```

So on page 2 or page 3

You can declare new variable like this:

```
string valueFromPageOne = HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"].ToString();
```